# Cannot read property of null, cant handle DOM manipulations, All elements in the web page is set to null

Tags: javascript, dom

Can't handle DOM manipulation, getting an error called, cannot read property "..." of null

Am designing a JS game, for that game, i need to do code some DOM manipulations, but when i try to develop some game functionalities, i am having an error in console window showing cannot read property '...' of null, And by inspecting i found that all the elements are set to null ,but the id tags are well handled, dont know how to resolve this issue.

the following is the html code

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
        <img src="img/enemy.png" class="img-responsive animate" id="enemy-1">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <img src="img/enemy.png" class="img-responsive animate" id="enemy-2">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <img src="img/enemy.png" class="img-responsive animate" id="enemy-3">
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The following part is the Javascript section

```
var shootingSound = new Audio('shoot.mp3');
  var bgCanvas = document.getElementById("#enemy-1");
  if(bgCanvas)
  {
  bgCanvas.addEventListener("click", function (){
    //shooty.play();
    shootingSound.play();
  });
  }
  else{
  console.log("Checky");
  }
```

I want the shooting sound to play when the img is clicked, but i am getting the else condition, "Checky" is logged into the console.

Comment: Don't include the `#` when using `getElementById()`.

Comment: This kind of things happen mostly because you are trying to find elements or attach event listeners to them when they are not ready.. when they are not in the DOM yet. You need to exceute your scripts after the DOM is loaded, you can make it in several ways depending on what u are using. Jquery, react, vue ,etc..

Comment: I deleted the #, but still the else condition is only functioning, i dont get the If - condition.

Comment: @CristianS. oh Ok bro, I am using Jquery, will u please suggest me some ways to resolve this?

Comment: Wrap your funcionality in a document.ready from jquery. http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: i have written some code inside $(window).on('load',....), Now i am not getting the else block, but the Audio is not playing... Note: i tried in chrome browser

Answer (score 0):

getElementById does not use the hash symbol that jQuery uses. That line should be:

```
    var bgCanvas = document.getElementById("enemy-1");
```

EDIT

```
<audio id="audio">
    <source src="shoot.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
</audio>
```

```
    document.getElementById("audio").play()
```

Comment: removal of # symbol is not helping, i resolved the actual issue by wrapping the content into a document. ready(), now i am not getting the else block but the audio is not playing...

Comment: You can create an audio object within the html and with the js play it: